# How to create event with a specific date in fullcalendar philippfrenzel using select option

Tags: php, yii2, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying to use the select option to create an event with a Modal with the selected date using Full Calendar - Philippfrenzel but I don't know how.

I already have an event Click which works but that it's not what I really want.

**Controller:**

```
    public function actionRequisitar(){
    $searchModel= new RequisicaoSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $events = [];
    foreach(Requisicao::find()->all() as $requisicao){
        $event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
        $event->id = $requisicao->id;
        $event->title = $requisicao->motivo_requisicao;
        $event->start = $requisicao->data_inicio_req;
        $events[] = $event;
    }
    return $this->render('requisitar',[
        'events'=>$events,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Requisicao();
    //$model->data_inicio_req=$date;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id, 'utilizador_id' => $model->utilizador_id, 'sala_id' => $model->sala_id]);
    }

    return $this->renderAjax('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**Index:**

```
   <?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
                'events' => $events,
                'id' => 'calendar',
            ));
            ?>
```

**Main.js**

```
   $(function () {
    $('#modalButton').click(function () {
        $('#modal').modal('show')
            .find('#modalContent')
            .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.fc-day', function () {
        var date = $(this).attr('data-date');
        $.get('index.php?r=requisicao/create', {'date': date}, function (data) {
            $('#modal').modal('show')
                .find('#modalContent')
                .load(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to pop up a modal whenever the user selects an empty area of the calendar? Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting . There are some examples too including source code

Answer (score 0):

Inside the configuration of Index where you setup the fullcalendar widget:

```
 <?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
                'events' => $events,
                'id' => 'calendar',
     ));
 ?>
```

You **must add the property** `eventClick` that triggers an JS function once an event is clicked.

You can do it like this:

```
<?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
                    'events' => $events,
                    'id' => 'calendar',
                    'eventClick' => new JsExpression('(event) => handleClick(event)'),            
     ));
?>
```

Notice that handleClick has to be a real function that is declared in your javascript, you could change `handleClick(event)` for `console.log(event)` to check if it is working as you expect before creating the function.